# How can access EJB from a remote client?

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, eclipse-jee

This is the scenario:
I created an EJB project in eclipse on wildfly as a server. The EJB project
It has been deployed with its beans, and is ready in the wildfly administrative console.

Now I need to create a remote client to use the EJB project beans.
I understand that this is done through a context lookup. Therefore, it included the following code in the client:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
// lookup the bean     Foo interface lives inside the remote EJB
Foo beanRemoteInterface = (Foo) ctx.lookup("myapp/myejbmodule/FooBean!org.myapp.ejb.Foo");
```

The problem is that, since the EJB and the client are in separate projects,
the Foo interface as unknown in the code from the client and I cannot have the client compile because the Foo type is not found.

- Is there any way to obtain this remote class reference on the client?
  -How can I make the client code compile in eclipse?

Comment: Just create shared library, put 'Foo' interface there and link this library to both EJB and client projects.

Comment: Yikes. I know they exist, but I haven't seen an RMI EJB project in... a very long time. Modern practice is generally to use Web services or message queues.

Comment: @AlexChernyshev: That could be a nice solution. However, I am concerned about how can we keep that library in sync at both sides when some future changes arrives.

Comment: There is no strict requirement for sync all the time - old compiled version on client side should work with updated server, till you not add breaking changes.  In case of  such - just rebuild library, client and server.